# Replace text during input change with jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm trying to replace text every time I've an input change.

Here's an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ewdp3Lnr/

```
$("[name='replacer']").on('change paste keyup', function() {
    PRO_Content = $('#content').html();
    PRO_Content = PRO_Content.replace('####', $("[name='replacer']").val());
    $('#content').html(PRO_Content);
});
```

It's working but only for the first change detected.

But not for the second, third, ...

Could you point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: your first value goes in a circle. here - `PRO_Content = $('# content').html();`

Answer (score 1):

Just get the content before any change and use the initial value. Don't rewrite the initial value because that will replace `####`

```js
var pattern = $('#content').html();
$("[name='replacer']").on('change paste keyup', function() {   
    PRO_Content = pattern.replace('####', $("[name='replacer']").val());
    $('#content').html(PRO_Content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Put something here to replace the #### in the HTML code:<br>
<input type="text" name="replacer">

<hr>

<span id="content">
  <p>This man is <strong style="color:red">####</strong>.</p>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Last thing, if I have more than one '####' how can I proceed please?

Comment: @Ross you need to use [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)

Comment: For example: 
`let i = 0;
let changes = ["first", "second"]; 
'#### something else ####'.replaceAll('####', () =>{ return changes[i++];});`

Comment: Hi @Ross if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code using [.text( function )](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function).

Moreover, instead of change and keyup evets you can use the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event.

The snippet:

```js
var element = $('#content :contains("####")').filter((i,e) => e.textContent == '####');
$("[name='replacer']").on('input paste', function(e) {
    element.text(function(idx, text) {
        return e.target.value;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" name="replacer">

<hr>

<span id="content">
  <p>This man is <strong style="color:red">####</strong>.</p>
</span>
```

Comment: Hello, it's woking but I'm looking for a more customizable way. Actually your code it too much based on the HTML structure and not on the key (i.e.: ####).

Comment: @Ross Snippet updated. Now I save the element where change the text content...... IN any case I don't see why use a **replace**. Let me know.